# Re-arrange list items based on alphabet?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if this is possible. I have some code below:

```
<p class="page_classList">
<strong>Crops:</strong>
<br>
<span class="cropElem">Berries - Blueberries</span>
<span class="cropElem">Peas</span>
<span class="cropElem">Squash</span>
<span class="cropElem">Okra</span>
</p>
```

Is there any way to have these spans display themselves in alphabetical order (by crop). This list is displayed when a user clicks on a farm page that is built in wordpress. Can a script rearrange these as the page loads?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Absolutely a script can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you already have events set up on your elements, you might not want to recreate them, but rather reorder them. Here is how I would do it:

```js
var container = $('.page_classList'),
    data      = $('.cropElem');

data.sort(function(a,b){
  if($(a).html() > $(b).html()) return 1;
  if($(a).html() < $(b).html()) return -1;
  return 0;
});

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  container.append(data[i]);
}
```

```css
.cropElem{ display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="page_classList">
<strong>Crops:</strong>
<br>
<span class="cropElem">Berries - Blueberries</span>
<span class="cropElem">Peas</span>
<span class="cropElem">Squash</span>
<span class="cropElem">Okra</span>
</p>
```

> **Why use `append`?**
>
> When you do `append` of an element, it does not duplicate it, it moves it. This allows you to reorder your elements.

Comment: This method worked perfectly for my situation. appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 2):

You loop through and find all the crop elements, delete the element and save the crop name into a list. Sort the list then loop through the list and re-add each element to the `<p>` this time they will be alphabetical since the list is sorted alphabetically using `.sort()`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d7wug6d8/

```
var spans = $(".page_classList").find(".cropElem");
var cropNames = [];
spans.each(function(index) {
  $(spans[index]).remove();
  cropNames.push($(spans[index]).html());
});
cropNames.sort();

$(cropNames).each(function(index) {
  $(".page_classList").append('<span class="cropElem">' + cropNames[index] + '</span>\n');
});
```

This gives the final HTML:

```
<p class="page_classList">
  <strong>Crops:</strong>
  <br>
  <span class="cropElem">Berries - Blueberries</span>
  <span class="cropElem">Okra</span>
  <span class="cropElem">Peas</span>
  <span class="cropElem">Squash</span>
</p>
```

For the new HTML you asked for: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d7wug6d8/1/

```
var foodItems = $(".page_classList").html().split(",");
foodItems.sort();
$(".page_classList").html(foodItems.join(", "));
```

Comment: It works in the jfiddle, but when i place the jquery link to 2.2.3 and your script in the footer.php file, just above the </body> tag nothing happens. DO I need to do something else? Thanks!

Comment: @gdeleon101 You should post the full code you have now as an edit to your op so we can see what's wrong. When you've done that leave a comment here so I know to check back

Comment: Okay, I think I have wrong code. Here is the source:<p class="page_classList">Lettuce - Romaine,Onions,Broccoli,Cauliflower,Lettuce - Artisan,Celery, Broccoli - Artisan,Lettuce - Green Leaf,Lettuce - Red Leaf,Lettuce - Boston,Lettuce - Sweet Gem</p> Is there a script to look at this <p class="page_List"> content and reorder them alphabetically? They are separated with a comma.

Comment: @gdeleon101 I've edited my post to show how to do it with that html too

Answer (score 0):

That is basically what you would do I dont feel like finishing the code though.  Then you could loop through the cropArray and output it in between the html span elements.

```
var cropArray = ["Berries - Blueberries", "Peas", "Squash", "Okra"];
cropArray.sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply:

Grab a collection of `spans`, sort them, and re-append with newly sorted collection.

```js
var els = $('.cropElem');

els.sort(function (a, b) {
    a = $(a).text();
    b = $(b).text();
    
    // compare
    if(a > b) {
        return 1;
    } else if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});

$('.page_classList').append(els);
```

```css
span { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="page_classList">
  <strong>Crops:</strong>
  <br>
  <span class="cropElem">Berries - Blueberries</span>
  <span class="cropElem">Peas</span>
  <span class="cropElem">Squash</span>
  <span class="cropElem">Okra</span>
</p>
```